# How to prune/delete nodes in nested/tree-like JSON?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following JSON example to represent a tree.

```
[
    {
        "label": "node1",
        "children": [
            {
                "label": "Human"
            },
            {
                "label": "Chimpanzee"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "node2",
        "children": [
            {
                "label": "node3",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "label": "Rat"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Mouse"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "BigRat"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I would like to do now, is the following:
Given a list of labels (e.g. BigRat, Mouse), how can I delete the corresponding nodes in the JSON?

I just can't get my head around this.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Use a `for.. in` loop or `Object.keys` with a normal loop to iterate the elements of an object and a normal for loop to iterate arrays. Remove elements from objects by using `delete` or setting them to null  - from arrays by using splice.

Comment: I assume by the time you're doing this, you're **not** dealing with JSON (which is a textual serialization form), but rather an object graph in memory?

Comment: You might want to remove the _visualization_ of the nodes and _not_ change the JSON itself... For that, showing your D3.js script would help _us_ help _you_..

Comment: On the other hand, if you actually want to edit your JSON, this has nothing to do with d3.js, so you should clear that out for everyone...

Answer (score 9):

Since your tree is essentially an object array, where each object has a label and an optional child array, what you need to prune are array elements, either in the main tree array or in one of it's branches.

You definitely do not want to use `delete` to delete array elements, since that leaves you with a sparse array.  Instead, you should `splice` out array elements.

You should, on the other hand, use `delete` to remove object properties, like `children` once they're empty.  Here's the code I would use:

```
function prune(array, label) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        var obj = array[i];
        if (obj.label === label) {
            // splice out 1 element starting at position i
            array.splice(i, 1);
            return true;
        }
        if (obj.children) {
            if (prune(obj.children, label)) {
                if (obj.children.length === 0) {
                    // delete children property when empty
                    delete obj.children;

                    // or, to delete this parent altogether
                    // as a result of it having no more children
                    // do this instead
                    array.splice(i, 1);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now assuming your tree was called `tree` and the label you wanted pruned was `node3`, you would call prune like so:

```
var wasItPruned = prune(tree, "node3");
```

Comment: it works, but how do you delete internal nodes. In case you deleted two leaf nodes, you want to delete the corresponding parent node as well.

Comment: edited code to demonstrate the alternative of deleting the parent as a result of it having no more children